# Single word for staying late at the office

Tags: word-request

I've heard a lot of single words meaning "staying late at the office", but I'm not able to recall them at the moment. What word can I use to describe this?

Answer (score 2):

The best (and only) one word description I can think of is working *overtime*.

> Lisa was out sick yesterday, so the boss had me take her place and work *overtime*.